# In Confluence Cloud is there a way to create a link within a Page to a Heading in the same Page?

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

The current workaround I use for this is to publish the Page, copy the link for the Heading and then edit the Page again to use the link. This "works" inside Confluence but when exporting to PDF the link always navigates to the top of the document.

Is there a specific macro for this functionality?

Comment: add a "#" and then the text of the heading (case sensitive!) to the pages address where you want to link to. See the Atlassian page https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-links-and-anchors/ for more information

Comment: thanks, that is must quicker than publishing and re-editing! Still doesn't seem to work with PDF outputs though :(